# JMeter how to select randomely from a extracted set of values

Tags: performance, groovy, jmeter, load-testing, jsr223

I have a requirement to use randome url from a url list I extract from a json response.

Say I extract them in this mannser

```
imageUrls_1=https://blah01.com
imageUrls_2=https://blah02.com
imageUrls_3=https://blah03.com
imageUrls_4=https://blah04.com
imageURLs_matchNr=4
```

In a following JSSR223 sampler I was able to generate a variable called "url" with one of the url names selected randomely
*("imageUrls_1","imageUrls_2",etc)*

I was thinking to use them in my HTTP request to get the correcponding url as follows. ***${${url}}***. But soon found out its not giving me anything other than `"${${url}}"` :(.

***JMeter Is it possible to place a varibale inside a varible name?***

Basically I need to use one of the extracted urls randomely in my HTTP request.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is going for [__V()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) and [__Random()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) functions combination like:

```
${__V(imageUrls_${__Random(1,${imageURLs_matchNr},)},)}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables)

Answer (score 0):

Use [__V](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) function

```
 ${__V(url)}
```

> The V (variable) function returns the result of evaluating a variable name expression.