# I am trying to add a username and string combined to a variable in Jmeter

Tags: json, jmeter

I have the username in the variable ${user} which has some numeric value like 2477492936 I want to pass this variable combined with some other value into the url path as id.

The post url path
[https://qwert.add.com/${id}?Type=order](https://qwert.add.com/$%7Bid%7D?Type=order)

In the loop controller under the http request I have declared a user-defined variable with name id and value as
${user}${__RandomString(2,abcdef)}

When I run the post request the id in the path is shown something like ${user}ca

Can I know why isn't taking the user value because outside the loop if I used ${user}..its picking up the user value

The user variable I am giving from a csv file

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65228974/jmeter-how-to-select-randomely-from-a-extracted-set-of-values/65229533#65229533

Comment: I have tried it but the ${user} value that I sent through csv file is not being picked up in the result it's just showing ${user}tu

Comment: Did you tried `${__V(${user}${__RandomString(2,abcdef)}}` ?

Comment: Yes, later I used the beanshell pre processor and it's working fine
Thank you